# Check if object is list of lists of strings?

Tags: python, functional-programming

What is the *elegant* way to check if object is list of lists of strings, without nested loops? Probably here must be conventional ways to construct structured iterations.

### UPD

Something like this:

```
l = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 1], 3, ['e', 2, 'f']]

def recurse(iterable, levels):
    results = []
    try:
        fn = levels[0]
    except IndexError:
        return
    for e in iterable:
        results.append(fn(e))
        try:
            results.extend(recurse(e, levels[1:]))
        except TypeError:
            pass
    return results

instance_of = lambda t: lambda e: isinstance(e, t)
print(recurse(l, [instance_of(list), instance_of(basestring)]))
```

### UPD #2

Ive made some kind of homebrew functional programming, now it checks for list of lists of lists of strings:

```
from collections import Iterable
from itertools import imap, chain


def compose(f, g):
    return lambda *a, **kw: f(g(*a, **kw))

def concat(iterable):
    return chain.from_iterable(iterable)

def mk_iter(o):
    if isinstance(o, Iterable):
        return o
    else:
        return [o]

def put_in(f, g):
    """To support spirit of the Olympics :)"""
    return lambda e: concat(
        [mk_iter(f(e)),
         concat(imap(compose(mk_iter, g), mk_iter(e)))]
    )


ckr = lambda t: lambda e: isinstance(e, t)

l = [[['a', 'b'], ['c']], [['d'], ['1']], [1]]

fns = [ckr(list), ckr(list),ckr(list), ckr(str)]
fns.reverse()

print(list(reduce(lambda x, y: put_in(y, x), fns)(l)))
```

Comment: What counts as a nested loop for you?

Comment: The task's nature is to test everything in every element of a list.  That's a nested loop on the logical level.  Each attempt to do it otherwise (using `chain` or similar) will only lead to hiding that fact.

Comment: @JanneKarila everything with lots of `for`'s and nesting :)

Answer (score 2):

```
lol = [["a", "b"], ["c"], ["d", "e"], [1]]

from itertools import chain
print isinstance(lol, list) and all(isinstance(items, list) \
        and all(isinstance(item, str) for item in items) for items in lol)
```

Comment: `and all(isinstance(item, list) for item in list_of_lists) and isinstance(list_of_list, list)` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> lls = [ ["he","li"],["be","b"],["c","n","o"],["f","ne","na"] ]
>>> isinstance(lls,list) and all([ all(isinstance(y,str) for y in x) and isinstance(x,list) for x in lls])
True
>>> not_lls = [ ["he","li"],["be",1]]
>>> isinstance(lls,list) and all([ all(isinstance(y,str) for y in x) and isinstance(x,list) for x in not_lls])
False
>>> not_also_lls = [ ["he","li"],{}]
>>> isinstance(lls,list) and all([ all(isinstance(y,str) for y in x) and isinstance(x,list) for x in not_also_lls])
False
```

Comment: @thefourtheye nice catch, added the check for main list also

Comment: he he he... Now compare this answer with my answer... :)

Comment: I'd prefer not to build useless lists, so just strip the `[]`.  And swap the check to avoid running into an error when testing `[3]`: `isinstance(lls, list) and all(isinstance(x, list) and all(isinstance(y, str) for y in x) for x in lls)`

Answer (score 1):

In a more generic way:

```
def validate(x, types):
    if not isinstance(x, types[0]):
        raise ValueError('expected %s got %s for %r' % (types[0], type(x), x))
    if len(types) > 1:
        for y in x:
            validate(y, types[1:])
```

Usage:

```
try:
    validate(
        [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 1], 3, ['e', 2, 'f']],
        [list, list, str])
except ValueError as e:
    print e  # expected <type 'str'> got <type 'int'> for 1
try:
    validate(
        [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'X'], 3, ['e', 2, 'f']],
        [list, list, str])
except ValueError as e:
    print e # expected <type 'list'> got <type 'int'> for 3

try:
    validate(
        [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'X'], ['3'], ['e', '2', 'f']],
        [list, list, str])
except ValueError as e:
    print e
else:
    print 'ok' # ok
```

Answer (score 0):

Plain and straight forward:

```
def isListOfStrings(los):
  return isinstance(los, list) and all(isinstance(e, str) for e in los)

def isListOfListOfStrings(lolos):
  return isinstance(lolos, list) and all(isListOfStrings(los) for los in lolos)

print isListOfListOfStrings([["foo"]])
```

I can't recommend a *recursion* here because the test for the outer does not really resemble the test for the inner.  Recursions are more useful if the depth of the recursion isn't fixed (as in this case) and the task is similar on each level (not the case here).

Comment: Try `isListOfListOfStrings(1)`