# Is there a way to check if object is List or List of Lists in Java

Tags: java, list, instanceof

I have a method receiving List type objects.
It can be List of Strings or List of Lists of Strings.
Is there a way to distinguish between these two kinds of objects in Java?
I already saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22768663/how-to-know-if-a-java-object-is-a-list) question, but in my case AFAIK in both cases the objects are `instanceof List`.
I also saw several similar questions about lists of lists in Python like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21723910/check-if-object-is-list-of-lists-of-strings).
But still didn't see the way to distinguish between List of Strings and List of Lists of Strings in Java.

Comment: Loop through the list and check each object with `instanceof`. See if each object is also a list.

Comment: This is an idea, thanks! But is there some better way to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "better"?

Comment: Kind of existing method like `instanceof` to apply on those objects to distinguish between them, without iterating on them to check that.

Comment: No there isn't.  The parameter types of generic types are erased at runtime.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong about my suggestion. I forgot different type arguments to a generic type don't change the method signature, meaning you can't create an overload like I was describing.

Comment: @Slaw it's ok, thanks

Comment: Though note you could create two methods with different names that accept the appropriate type. That makes it the caller's responsibility to call the right method.

Comment: This is what I currently have. Just wanted to make it more general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Specifically, all lists are just lists, at runtime, generics is **gone**. If the compiler / editor can't tell you, then there's nothing you can do that'll tell you at runtime either.

To make this a little more specific, there is **zero** difference between these two:

```
void example() {
    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<List<String>> list2 = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
}
```

100% identical - nothing you could possibly do with these lists in any way or form to tell them apart.

You can hack around it - for example, given a `List<?>`, if you run `.get(0)` on this and the thing you get is a `List` (again, not possible to tell that it is a `List<String>` or a `List<WhoKnowsWhat>`, just that it is some list), then clearly it wasn't a list of strings. Could be a list of Objects, or a list of lists of lists of maps of strings to integers. No way to know.

If the list is empty this hack doesn't work. It's not a good idea.

### So what's the solution?

Fix your code. You shouldn't have been in the scenario in the first case. Somewhere in your codebase, you create either a list of strings OR a list of lists of strings, and then return it. Do not do this, instead figure out another way. For example, with a type hierarchy:

```
public interface FullName {
    public List<String> allNames();
    public String rendered();
    public List<String> get(int idx);
}
```

and then write implementations for each of the various 'forms'. Here's an implementation given an input of `List<String>`:

```
private class SimpleName implements FullName {
    private final List<String> name;

    public SimpleName(List<String> name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override public List<String> allNames() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override public String rendered() {
        return name.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
    }

    @Override public List<String> get(int idx) {
        if (idx == 0) return name;
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
}
```

The point is mostly that code that interacts with these shouldn't need to care about what kind of name you have; whatever operations you can imagine having to do to 'a name' should be encapsulated in this interface and the different implementations can contain all relevant knowledge (represented in code) as to how to do these tasks. In the exotic case that calling code really does need to know, they can - either expose methods, or just do instanceof checks.

Comment: Thank you very much for a great explanations! But I will fix the problem on other level, as you mentioned - I will not be in this scenario.